# How is for of implemented in JS

Tags: javascript, v8

I like to know how `for of` is implemented in JS and how it works behind the scenes.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), `for of` loops over an iterable object.

My question is: For iterable objects with a sense of **order** (like arrays), does it respect that order when looping? Is it a requirement per the specifications? Can I count on it or should I use a `for loop` if I want the elements in a particular order.

I assume that it depends on the implementation of the iterable protocol by that particular object (Arrays in this case) and `for of` is just a consumer, but at the end of the day I wasn't able to find anything specific about whether order is preserved or not.

BTW, I made some tests mainly in Chrome's V8 and it seems that order is preserved when looping over arrays.

Comment: [iteration protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) the order is as the iterator defines it - arrays are iterated by their indices (smaller to greater).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) is implement behind the scenes using an iterator.

[This](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es6-iterables-and-iterators-de18b54f4d4) is a nice short article that explains how the iterator works.

Here's an example of a custom iterator that may help you understand how it works under the hood. You need to implement a `[Symbol.iterator]` method:

```js
const iterable = {
 [Symbol.iterator](){
  let index = -1;
  const iter = {
   next(){
    index++;
    if(index === 0)      return {value: 'This is index 0', done: false}
    else if(index === 1) return {value: 'This is index 1!', done: false}
    else if(index === 2) return {value: 'This is index 2!!', done: false}
    else if(index === 3) return {value: 'This is index 3!!!', done: false}

                                return {value: 'end', done: true};
   }
  }

         return iter;
 }
}

const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator.next()); // 0
console.log(iterator.next()); // 1
console.log(iterator.next()); // 2
console.log(iterator.next()); // 3
console.log(iterator.next()); // end
```

As you can see [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-%25arrayiteratorprototype%25.next), the `next` method of the Array iterator is implemented with this pseudo code:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @amir-popvich, this looks good. So, according to the ECMAScript specification, JS implementors of the iterator protocol are required to respect order if there is one. Did I get that correctly?

Comment: If you could add this somewhere at the beginning of your answer would be great, because that was a crucial part of the question and would benefit future readers. Thanks.